# How can I optimize tech research?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-2

I will use an example. I'm going to to research X-Tech. This tech needs:

- Artillery Skill 3
- Artillery Skill 3
- Org Skill 3
- Org Skill 3
- Electronics 3

I have two research groups to choose from:

- XYZ; Skill 4; Artillery Skill and Org Skill
- ZYX; Skill 3; Artillery Skill, Org Skill and Electronic

Which group would complete the research faster?

Comment: Hey, @iber.  We take the game name out of the title because it's redundant; SEO already adds it into the title.  Right now, your question title is, "hearts of iron 2 - How can I optimize tech research in HoI2?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is more important to cover more fields of the tech by the techteam, then it is to have a high skill in the areas covered.

So in the example you give, ZYX should finish the research faster than XYZ would.

When the difference between skill becomes larger, and there's only one field missing from the more skilled team the situation changes, in that case the more skilled team will finish the job quicker. A Skill-8 team with 4 matching fields is usually faster than a Skill-6 team with 5 fields, for example.

However, there are some exceptions. If you build a nuclear reactor or rocket test site those sites will add skill in nuclear/rocketry fields to any research team conducting research in those areas.

So if you are researching technology that requires:

- nuclear skill
- nuclear skill
- nuclear skill
- mathematics skill
- organizational skill

A tech team with just nuclear skill will outperform a tech team with math/organizational skill if you have no nuclear reactor, but if you do have a reactor the math/organizational team will be your preferred choice.

There are several other factors which influence tech research speed like blueprints or the tech's historical year.

A great article to read trough if you want to know more about the math behind research speeds is the [article on the HOI 2 wiki about research](http://www.paradoxian.org/hoi2wiki/index.php/Research)

If you want to figure out who is the absolute fastest team to get a certain tech I would recommend using a [tool like the research tool](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?476166-Hearts-of-Iron-II-Research-Assistant-2.0) as all the different factors which influence research speed can make making the right choice very hard.